# Android Studio creates new project with empty page showing the error gradle "myapplication3" project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, heap-memory

when create new project in android studio i get a error message

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

  1.Open the projects
  **gradle.properties**
  file in android studio

  2.Added this line at end of file
  **org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m**
  & Save the file

  3.Close & reopen the project

Comment: sir where to find  gradle.properties ?

Comment: Right click on your project in android studio than click **show in explorer** option than you will find **gradle.properties** file, open it with notepad++ and add **org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m**.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Invalidate caches/ restart and then build the project after restart.it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with Gradle 4.1.

I fixed it by updating my gradle version in `ProjectHome/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` from `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2-all.zip`